# Obj-C - Adding interval of times to NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add a series of hour intervals to an NSMutableArray using the below code. I'm successfully able to add the times to self.dailyTimes inside the method (the first log returns with my array of hours), however when I log self.dailyTimes the second time outside of the method, the only time that shows up in the log is 12:00AM. Any idea why the full range of times isn't appearing when I log the array outside of the method?

**ViewController.m**

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad {
    
    [super viewDidLoad]
    
        
        NSString *startTime = @"12:00 AM";
        NSString *endTime = @"12:00 PM";
    
    
        NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
        NSDate* fromTime = [timeFormat dateFromString:startTime];
        NSDate* toTime = [timeFormat dateFromString:endTime];
        NSDate *dateByAddingThirtyMinute ;
        NSTimeInterval timeinterval = [toTime timeIntervalSinceDate:fromTime];
        NSLog(@"time Int %f",timeinterval/3600);
        float numberOfIntervals = timeinterval/3600;
        NSLog(@"Start time %f",numberOfIntervals);
    
        for(int iCount = 0;iCount < numberOfIntervals*1 ;iCount ++)
        {
            dateByAddingThirtyMinute = [fromTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600];
            fromTime = dateByAddingThirtyMinute;
            NSString *formattedDateString;
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
            formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateByAddingThirtyMinute];
            NSLog(@"Time after 60 min %@",formattedDateString);
            
            self.dailyTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [self.dailyTimes addObject:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateByAddingThirtyMinute]];
            NSLog(@"First log: The daily times are %@",self.dailyTimes);
          
         
        }
        
        NSLog(@"Second log:The daily times are %@",self.dailyTimes);
    
        
          }
```

Comment: logging is not complete outside of the method viewDidLoad or outside of the for loop?
the first will be getter/setter problem the other a scope issue. And hello again! :D

Comment: Sorry, I meant outside the for loop! :) E.g. I'm trying to use the array inside my tableview. Logging the array anywhere outside the loop (even after I add the times to it) just gives me 12:00 inside the array. @OlSen

Comment: actually obvious. :) your for loop is allocating the array over and over again. declare and allocate/init the array outside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialised the variable `self.dailyTimes` inside for loop. so it is initialize and again and again. Pull it outside of `for` loop. then it work

```
self.dailyTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int iCount = 0;iCount < numberOfIntervals*1 ;iCount ++)
{
    dateByAddingThirtyMinute = [fromTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600];
    fromTime = dateByAddingThirtyMinute;
    NSString *formattedDateString;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateByAddingThirtyMinute];
    NSLog(@"Time after 60 min %@",formattedDateString);
    
    [self.dailyTimes addObject:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateByAddingThirtyMinute]];
    NSLog(@"First log: The daily times are %@",self.dailyTimes);
    
}
NSLog(@"Second log:The daily times are %@",self.dailyTimes);
```